# Dropbox REST API 400 error when uploading file

Tags: dropbox-api

Recently the dropbox api has been giving me 404 errors when uploading a file. Same code has been working for months. Has anything changed? I'm accessing the rest api through sharpbox.

Error response is below. Part of the request I'm making is below that.

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 13:20:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Dropbox-Request-Id: ed356744df5e9541856f727505cceee0
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex

2e
{"error": {"file": "Expecting a file upload"}}
0
```

Request:

```
POST https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/VMDVGZION?file=test.pdf&oauth_consumer_key=0o1pqhuy0ul766h&oauth_nonce=f74c8207d9a741929529f1a662804e66&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1459171240&oauth_token=0apqmt3p17e6s69z&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=8i0QAVDTIDyQPUMNZTfDWdFDiyM%3d HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Host: api-content.dropbox.com
Content-Length: 292539

-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.pdf";
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ

..

-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

Comment: Looks like something changed on dropboxes side. From a dropboxer on their forum:

The /1/files (POST) endpoint is an old upload method on the Core API, a.k.a. API v1. That endpoint is technically supported, and it looks like its behavior did change, which we're looking in to.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206218576-404-error-when-uploading-file-through-REST-API- ]

Comment: The /files (POST) endpoint should be working again now. Please let me know if you're still seeing any issues.

Comment: Everything working as normal. Thanks!